# Updating If/Else statement from a Boolean value when a button is clicked

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have a user input search bar where the user will input their **"City"**, **"Address"**, and **"State"**. Then the user will click the search button, which will change to a Boolean value to equal **'true'**. This Boolean value is then past to my function which will go though a If/Else condition. **If the Boolean = 'true'**: then it includes the 'City' and 'State' (So I can get the 9 (or less) recent "Signed" opportunities from the 'city' & 'State' to the array). **Else** the Boolean will just set to the 9 most recent "Signed" opportunities to the array (without narrowing the array down via 'city' & 'state').

***The error message:***
[image]

**mapping.js Code (with SearchClick button):**

***(`UpdateOpportunities` is the Boolean value)***

```
// Method for when the search button is clicked in the "mappingBox" LWC.
    SearchClick(message) {

        if(message.operator == true){

            // The address entered into the search bar.
            const ArrStreet = SearchString.split(',');
            SearchStreet = ArrStreet[0];

            // The town or city entered into the search bar.
            const ArrCity = SearchString.split(',');
            SearchCity = ArrCity[1];

            UpdateOpportunities = true;

            // Updates and locates the location searched.
            this.mapMarkers = MapMarkers(SearchCity, SearchState, SearchStreet, ClickData, UpdateOpportunities);

        }

    }
```

**MapMarkers.js Code:**

```
export function MapMarkers(SearchCity, SearchState, SearchStreet, Opportunities, UpdateOpportunities){
   
   let NineRecentOpportunities;
   let validStages;
   let validCity;
   let validState;

   if(UpdateOpportunities == true){

       // Sets the 9 most recent "Signed" opportunities in the searched: 'City & State' to the array.
       validStages = ['Signed', 'Signed LOI'];
       validCity = [SearchCity];
       validState = [SearchState];
       NineRecentOpportunities = Opportunities.filter(
       (record) => validCity.indexOf(record.Service_City__c) > -1, validState.indexOf(record.Service_State__c) > -1, validStages.indexOf(record.StageName) > -1 ).slice(-9);


   } else {

       // Sets the 9 most recent "Signed" opportunities to the array.
       validStages = ['Signed', 'Signed LOI'];
       NineRecentOpportunities = Opportunities.filter(
       (record) => validStages.indexOf(record.StageName) > -1 ).slice(-9);

   }
```

**Refined Question:**

The **Else-statement** seems to be working for me giving me all the 9 most recent "Signed" opportunities to the array. But the **If-statement** isn't narrowing the array down by 'city' & 'state' of the 9 or less recent "Signed" opportunities. Is it because It will fail if their are less-then 9 "Signed" opportunities in that city, or is it the Boolean value that's not pasting correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the && (and) operator to check more than one condition.

```
NineRecentOpportunities = Opportunities.filter(
    (record) => (
       validCity.indexOf(record.Service_City__c) > -1 && 
       validState.indexOf(record.Service_State__c) > -1 && 
       validStages.indexOf(record.StageName) > -1
    )
).slice(-9);
```

Comma has some special behavior based on context. Inside of a function call parameter list, the comma separates the individual parameters. Therefore, it was as if you were only filtering by one condition, the city. When the second parameter tried to be evaluated, it was undefined in any scope, because you were now outside the arrow function.

The outer parentheses after `=>` avoids potentially ambiguous code reading, and the `&&` operator evaluates the left-hand operand first, and only if that operand is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), it then evaluates the right-hand operand. This means that the code runs very slightly faster, since it knows that the right-hand operand can't make the result true.

Comment: I get a error: `"[Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Service_Street__c')]"` when I try searching my location. I this because I have less then 9 recent "Signed" opportunities?

Comment: @Pinto The error isn't in this code, as there's no `Service_Street__c` in the code on this page. My guess is that you have a magic number in your code somewhere, for example, `for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {` or some variant, where you run off the end of the Array into undefined records.

Comment: Yes, I have a for-loop exactly like the one you shown. It "creates a address string, and stores them to an array." So I can display it to the marker-box. can I do? `for(let i = 0; i < NineRecentOpportunities.length; i++) {`

Comment: @Pinto You could, but I'd really suggest you make use of the Array.map function: `let markers = NineRecentOpoortunities.map((record)=>({ location: { Street: record.Service_Street__c, City: record.Service_City__c, ... }}));` This is a fairly common style of code to write in JS. Let a code formatter pretty this up for you, I can't include newlines in comments.

Comment: I did my changes, and now getting a error:`"[Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Service_State__c')]"` Do this still have anything to do with my for-loop?

Comment: @Pinto What's your code look like now?

Comment: My for-loop looks like this: `for (let i = 0; i < NineRecentOpportunities.length; i++) {` Should I create a new question will all my code?

Comment: @Pinto Probably. We're pretty deep in comment territory.